# convert an encoded string to jpg and display it

Tags: flash, amf

I need to convert a base64 encoded string from a server (being sent via amf) to an image. on the server the raw image data (gif / jpeg / png) is being encoded to base64 (which already works fine), and I need to decode this string and display the image in my flash movie. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've converted your string to a ByteArray, you can create a Loader object and use LoadBytes to turn your binary object into a display object. Then add the loader to stage.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.loadBytes(yourBytesHere)

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
addChild(loader);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

convert it to ByteArray
if you need saving: as3corelib `package com.adobe.images.*`